# "sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected " issue in starlette

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I got the below error
"sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected, got <class 'schemas.PersonDetail'>."
My get.py is

```
from tkinter.tix import Select
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import PlainTextResponse, JSONResponse, RedirectResponse, Response
from db import engine, Session
from schemas import PersonDetail
from sqlmodel import Session, select

local_session = Session(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)


def GetMethod(request):
    return local_session.query(PersonDetail).all()
```

and schemas.py is

```
from lib2to3.pytree import Base
from pydantic import BaseModel
class PersonDetail(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'PersonDetail'
    name: str
```

Can anyone help me in solving this

Comment: the arg to `local_session.query` needs to be a SQLAlchemy db model, not a Pydantic model, see: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-the-database-models

Comment: try to follow a fastapi db tutorial